# Enlazar tecla enter con función

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

eproblema es que enlacé la tecla enter a una función el tkinter, pero ahora el botón no la reconoce. ¿Cómo hago para que ambos, la tecla y el botón activen la función? Cuando le doy al botón, parece:
TypeError: segunda_ventana() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("800x500")

def segunda_ventana(event):
    ventana2=customtkinter.CTkToplevel()

boton=customtkinter.CTkButton(command=segunda_ventana)
boton.grid()  

ventana.bind('<Return>', segunda_ventana)  
ventana.mainloop()
```

El ejemplo es tonto pero lo hago para que sea lo más corto posible.

Comment: Para hacer un argumento opcional, tenés que darle un valor predeterminado. En este caso podrías usar None, quedandote la definición de la función así `def segunda_ventana(event=None):` (Nota: si necesitas acceder al objeto Event que pasa tkinter como primer argumento cuando asocias un evento a una función, ten en cuenta que cuando la función se llama desde el botón, este objeto no se pasa y el argumento toma el valor predeterminado None).

Comment: Gracias @DanteS., ya lo solucioné

Comment: En la parte inferior de la pregunta, existe una caja de texto que dice "Tu Respuesta", por favor, incluye los pasos y el código que has realizado para dar solución a tu caso, de este modo serás el héroe de más personas que tengan el mismo escenario o uno muy similar, al mismo tiempo, colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Comment: Ok, na sabía. Pensaba que era para decir que había llegado a la conclusión yo solo. Gracias @fredyfx

Comment: Un placer colaborar con la comunidad de desarrolladores y con el sitio, éxitos con el desarrollo y a darle con todo el power 2.0!!! Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

Al final seguí el consejo de @DanteS. y agregué None a la función. Hace lo que debe hacer, funciona cuando doy Enter o cuando presiono el botón. Aquí dejo el código:

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("800x500")

def segunda_ventana(event=None):
    ventana2=customtkinter.CTkToplevel()

boton=customtkinter.CTkButton(command=segunda_ventana)
boton.grid()  

ventana.bind('<Return>', segunda_ventana)  
ventana.mainloop()
```